# Bash script to submit a series of jobs one after one?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run a series of jobs one after one using a bash script. In many directories named as calculation_01, calculation_02 etc. there are input files located (named as *.in) which should be invoked using "mpirun" and the corresponding runbinary.
The provided script runs all *.in files simultaneously and therefore the first job in the first directory "calculation_01" fails and the second job in the second directory "calculation_02" terminates normally.

```
#!/bin/bash

OutputFiles=()
CurrDir=$PWD
#outer for-loop to start the calculation within each directory
for dir in $CurrDir/calculation_*/
do
    cd $dir;
    #executable for running the input file *.in
    mpirun -n 4 *.in 
    #executable creates the output-file *.out in each directory
    files="/calculation_*/*.out"
    #inner for-loop to validate the output-file *.out whether the calculation has ended properly in each directory
    for outfile in *.out
    do
        if [[ "$(grep 'Normal Termination' $outfile)" != "" ]]
        then    
            OutputFiles+=(${outfile#*_})
        fi
    done    
done
```

Hence, I think that there is a problem with the logic of the for-loops. Which line of code do I need to rewrite in order to start the first calculation in the first directory "calculation_01" and validate this whether it terminated normally and if it ended normally then start the second job in the second directory "calculation_02"?

I am grateful for any help!

Comment: Perhaps use *a different name* for the second loop's variable? `i` is a terrible name too. `dir` for the first loop and `outfile` for the second would be much more expressive...

Comment: Thank you for the the hint! I edited my first post but I still encounter the same problem. One of the calculations fails the other one terminates normally. I think that I need to include somehow a "wait" to check the `*.log` file and then continue. In any case, when I execute the bash script it tells me that there is no `*.out` file to grep because it probably needs some time to create the file first...

Comment: `files` is never used. And after the first loop you are in the first `calculation_*` subdirectory -- not the parent directory where you started. Forgot to `cd ..` perhaps? And yes, if those jobs are started in the background, you need some mechanism to wait until they finished...

Comment: Yes, you are right that `files` is never being used. I also tried  `cd ../` but it didn't help. I think that the problem arises due to the first line of code where I force the script to change into the folder  `for dir in $CurrDir/calculation_*/` so that it enters both directories and runs the calculations simultaneously...

Comment: Use `set -x` to see what's happening. Check your script with https://www.shellcheck.net/. Use a subshell `()` so parent is unaffected by dir changes.

Comment: I have never used mpirun but man page says it returns 0 if all tasks were successful.  This implies it waits for all tasks.    It also has -wdir option if you want to outsouce the cd to it.  If you do it in shell using a sub-shell: ( cd ...; ) ensures you return to directory you started at.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your helpful comments. Whenever I invoked the script by sending it to the background like `./script.sh &` I realized that it finished one calculation in one directory successfully but failed for the second directory because it was trying to access the second directory simultaneously. This led to an I/O failure.

The solution to this is using the PID and waiting to finish the job within one directory before starting the next calculation in the second directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a pids
CurrDir=$PWD
#outer for-loop to start the calculation within each directory
for dir in $CurrDir/calculation_*/
do
    cd $dir;
    echo "$PWD"
    #executable for running the input file *.in
    mpirun -n 4 *.in 
    #executable creates the output-file *.out in each directory
    files="/calculation_*/*.out"
    #inner for-loop to validate the output-file *.out whether the calculation has ended properly in each directory
    for f in $files 
    do
      if grep -i "Normal Termination" $f
      then
      echo "Completed Successfully"
      grep -w "Energy" $f >> energy.txt
      fi
    done    
)
pids+=($!)
wait ${pids[*]}
done
```